# E.C. Titchmarsh's "The Riemann Zeta-Function"

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, riemann-zeta

I was reading "*The Riemann Hypothesis*" by J.E. Littlewood, in which I was interested by the following line:

*Titchmarsh [1] devised a method, of considerable theoretical interest, for calculating the zeros (of the Riemann Zeta function)*"

The *[1]* references the paper "The Riemann Zeta-Function" by E.C. Titchmarsh, published in 1951 in Oxford. Unfortunately, I was not able to find the paper online, Google does not yield any relevant results. Does someone know where I could find this paper?

Comment: The 1930 edition of the book is available at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/zetafunctionofri032076mbp) (124 pages only : the edition updated by Heath-Brown and linked by José Carlos Santos may be more relevant).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thank you for the link

Comment: it is [there](https://www.google.fr/search?q=titchmarsh+the+theory+of+the+riemann+zeta-function+pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a paper. It's the (first edition of the) book *[The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1CyfApMt8JYC&printsec=frontcover&hl=en-EN&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)*.